# Дублируется название атрибута в woocommerce_page_title() при выборе фильтра

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возникла проблема с дубликатом названия атрибута в woocommerce_page_title() при выборе фильтра.

Тема ИМ -Flatsome

Плагин фильтров - Premmerce Product Filter for WooCommerce.

[image: filter]

Comment: Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: @Андрей Lvovskiy у самого плагина есть настройки по управлению правилами, возможно Вы там допустили ошибку http://prntscr.com/1ebac4e, ну а так надо смотреть код...